# JSF 2 - clearing component attributes on page load?

Tags: validation, components, jsf-2

**The real question:** Is there a way to clear certain attributes for all components on an initial page load?

**Background info:**

In my application, I have a JSF 2.0 frontend layer that speaks to a service layer (the service layer is made up of Spring beans that get injected to the managed beans).

The service layer does its own validation, and I do the same validation in the frontend layer using my own validator classes to try and avoid code duplication somehow. These validator classes aren't JSF validators, they're just POJOs.

I'm only doing validation on an action, so in the action method, I perform validation, and only if it's valid do I call through to the service layer.

When I do my validation, I set the styleClass and title on the UIComponents using reflection (so if the UIComponent has the setStyleClass(:String) or setTitle(:String) methods, then I use them).

This works nicely, and on a validation error I see a nicely styled text box with a popup containing the error message if I hover over it. However, since the component is bound to a Session Scoped Managed Bean, it seems that these attributes stick. So if I navigate away and come back to the same page, the styleClass and title are still in the error state.

Is there a way to clear the styleClass and title attributes on each initial page load?

Thanks,

James

P.S. I'm using the action method to validate because of some issues I had before with JSF 1.2 and it's validation methods, but can't remember why... so that's why I'm using the action method to validate.

Comment: would I have to implement a PhaseListener? I could clear them for the components I want to clear them from in the managed bean, but a PhaseListener could avoid me having to manually do it for each component? I wouldn't be clearing the styleClass, just removing a certain 'error' class from it, so think it might be a possible solution... is a PhaseListener the way to go, and which phase should it act on, I assume the first phase

Comment: [ http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/jsf-error-fields-style/ ]

[ http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I must use a PhaseListener, see [this blog entry by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html) and [this other blog entry](http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/jsf-error-fields-style/), that's a much better way of doing what I'm doing already - setting the styleClass manually using reflection - which gets all components with messages and highlights them... I'm gonna do the same, however think it's possible to add an attribute instead, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I needed access to all components in the component tree. The PhaseListener doesn't have access to this, so using ViewHandler... not efficient. Still trying to find a better solution.